# JQM - Tab switch and auto refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

Tab switching - Am loading a page, which has a page url, Then i switch tab which makes an AJAX call to the server. Say i have auto-refresh for all the tabs, after second tab switch it goes back to the first tab because of auto-refresh. Please let me know how this should be handled properly, as i have many tabs within one tab where am doing AJAX there also.

Comment: wow, couldn't understand, `after second tab switch it goes back to the first tab because of auto-refresh` - How are you doing your auto-refresh ?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply add a tap event handler to your menu and re-load content every tab click

On every tab link you can add some data attribute like `data-target="mypage.html"`

and then just handle it:

```
$( "#mymenu a" ).on( 'tap', tapHandler );

function tapHandler(event) {
    var target = $(this).attr("data-target");

    $.get(target, function(data) {
        $('#my_content_div').html(data);
        $("#my_content_div").trigger("create"); // trigger pagecreate instead if loaded content includes headers or footers
    });

    return false;
}
```

Comment: The solution you have given is for just loading one tab. What should i do if the page refreshes for every 30 seconds automatically. Since am loading data using ajax, the url does not change even when i go to the second tab. When the page refreshes automatically, it should refresh the current tab that i am seeing right now.

Comment: `$.get` is a shorten ajax btw,  to refresh every 30 seconds just get the ajax request inside a js `setInterval()` like:  setInterval(yourrequest, 30000);

Comment: And the way i did it it works for loading every tab, not only 1, check that `$( "#mymenu a" ).on( 'tap', tapHandler );` includes every <a> inside menu div, if you have a child nav bar, just do the same for it